# Two points to form a line, how to find the distance between the line and a third point?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Given three points, pt1(x1,y1), pt2(x2,y2), pt3(x3,y3),
pt1 and pt2 form a straight line, how to calculate the minimum/perpendicular distance from the line to pt3?

Sorry for my bad English, I hope someone could understand what I am asking.

Comment: Hint. The shortest distance from $(u,v)$ to the line $A x+B y+C=0$ is $ |A u+B v +C|/\sqrt {A^2+B^2}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distance from the point (${x_3}$, ${y_3}$) to a straight line passing through points (${x_1}$, ${y_1}$), (${x_2}$, ${y_2}$) and written in its generic form $ax + by + c = 0$ is:

$$\frac{|{ax_3} + {by_3} + {c}|} {\sqrt{(a^{2} + b^{2})}}$$

Needless to say, $-\frac{a}{b}$ and $-\frac{c}{b}$ are the straight line's angular and linear coefficients, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

The points $P$ along the line are described by the equation $$P=\alpha p_1 + (1-\alpha)p_2.$$ If $P$ is the point on the line where the minimum occurs, then $p_3 - P$ is orthogonal to the straight line whose direction is given by the vector $p_2-p_1$. If $P$ is given by the value $\alpha$, the orthogonality condition reads algebraically: $$(p_3 - \alpha p_1 - (1-\alpha)p_3)\cdot(p_2 - p_1) = 0.$$ Solving for $\alpha$, we find $$ \alpha = \frac{\left( p_{3}-p_{2}\right) \cdot \left( p_{2}-p_{1}\right) }{\left( p_{2}-p_{1}\right) \cdot \left( p_{2}-p_{1}\right) }.$$ The rest should be straightforward.